# Why I can't write "mailto:" in DataNavigateUrlFields?

Tags: asp.net, email

In `GridView`, I am tring to use `HyperLinkField`,I am trying to write `'mailto:'` into it `DataNavigateUrlFields` parameter, but it renders to nothing: `<a href=''>...</a>`. Why?

Comment: Please don't use code sample function in editor just to highlight. You can use B instead if you want to emphasize something. And can you put the code you are using? The part where you write mailto:

Comment: What do you mean by "can't write"? It does not render, throws exception, anything?

Comment: @Kuzgun I don't see anything wrong with OP's usage of code blocks..

Comment: Can you show _how_ are you using `DataNavigateUrlFields` for this?

Comment: @Stijn, just found out it is discussed here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right

Answer (score 0):

There was some time discussion on MSDN forum. The result of this disscusion was to using `BoundField` instead of `HyperLinkField`

**UPDATE**

I found it in my notes. the working code is following:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Email" 
    DataFormatString="<a href=mailto:{0}>{0}</a>" 
    HtmlEncodeFormatString="false" 
    HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
```

And the discussion is here: [How to create mailto: in gridview?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1014242.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue using `HyperLinkField` with mailto.

References:

- http://forums.asp.net/t/1014242.aspx/1
- http://www.itjungles.com/dotnet/hyperlinkfield-mailto

Suggested workaround is to use a BoundField instead:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="SendTo" 
    DataFormatString="<a href=mailto:{0}>{0}</a>"   
    HtmlEncodeFormatString="false" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="SendTo" />
```

Or, alternatively, a HyperLink control within a template field:

```
<asp:TemplateField
HeaderText="E-mail"
SortExpression="Email">

<ItemTemplate>

<asp:HyperLink
ID="HyperLink1"
runat=server
Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>'
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Email", "mailto:{0}") %>'
/>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```